# Run tortoise SVN from Node.js

Tags: node.js, svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to run some simple commands for Tortoise SVN via a Node.js server? Essentially an update and commit on a repository.

Comment: TortoiseSVN is a GUI tool, thus unsuitable for that. But its package bundles the official command line tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `child_process` module to execute whatever shell script you want. Just figure out the svn commands you need to execute and refer to the [node js child_process docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process). You will need svn to be installed on the server your node process is running on.

Here is a simplified example:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const pathToRepo = findPathToRepoSomehow();
const svnUpdate = spawn('svn', ['update', pathToRepo]);

svnUpdate.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log('update successful!');
});
```

You would want to handle error conditions as well.